# Application fails to load inconsistently on iPhone 3G

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have two iPhone devices: 3G and 3GS. My application always loads successfully on iPhone 3GS but on iPhone 3G it loads like 10% of tries (but it loads). I do not have any exceptions or zombies.

Can someone lead me to possible causes or suggestions to how can i find root cause of the problem?

Comment: What happens in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method? Do you make any synchronous url requests or resource loads?

Comment: Synchronous requests may slow down your application launch which would make iOS to kill off your application if it didn't finish launching in under 30 seconds.

Comment: mmm.. thats interesting. I'll check this. this could be the problem

Comment: My check shows, that it takes 23 - 24 seconds between application launch and crash.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities. One of them is the "Images". Are you using a lot of images? What are the resolution. Remember:

iPhone 4, ipod touch use XX@2x resolution (retina image: 640 x 960 px)

iPhone 3 without @2x (smaller resolution: 320 x 480 px)

Comment: Yep I'm using lots of images. How this can affect application stability?